# How do I get the screen / display resolution?

Tags: rust, window, resolution

I am currently working on a game in Rust (Piston Crate) and I want to center the Window it creates. It allows me to change the window's offset from the top left of the screen. I want to get the resolution the operating system works in (screen / display / monitor resolution) and center the window based on that.

In Python for example, by using `pyautogui`, you can get the screen resolution using `pyautogui.size()`.

In Java, by using `java.awt`, you can get the screen resolution using `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()`.

Is there something similar in Rust I could use? (`std`- or any extern crate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I depends of the backend you use.
For example if you use the Winit / Glutin backend you can use the `MonitorHandle` struct, which has a `size()` method.

Docs:https://docs.rs/winit/0.26.1/winit/monitor/struct.MonitorHandle.html

or for Glutin https://docs.rs/glutin/0.28.0/glutin/window/struct.Window.html#method.available_monitors

The Glutin module also has a `dpi` module that can provide information. https://docs.rs/glutin/0.28.0/glutin/dpi/index.html

If you use SDL2 backend, you could take a look at the sdl2_sys module SDL_HINT_RENDER_LOGICAL_SIZE https://docs.rs/sdl2-sys/0.35.2/sdl2_sys/constant.SDL_HINT_RENDER_LOGICAL_SIZE_MODE.html